# sas conditional macro, logic not working

Tags: macros, sas, conditional-statements

I have this conditional macro that compiles with no errors, but the logic does not seem to work.  If hours is less than 2, should print "not enough" and if 2 or more than it should print something like "enough hours".

```
    %macro methours;

%if hours lt 2 %then footnote  'does not meet requirement ';

%else
 footnote ' is enough study hours ';

    %mend methours;
```

Answer (score 0):

The letter `h` is greater than the digit `2` so the `%ELSE` clause will always execute.  If `HOURS` is a macro variable then use `&hours` to test its value.

You might also need another semi-colon to mark the end of the FOOTNOTE statement. The ones you have now are part of the macro code.  You could add `%do` ... `%end` to make it clearer.

```
%if ... %then %do;
  footnote ... ;
%end;
```